# Best way to count days in period spitted by month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Need to example how to calculate the count of days in a period splited by month.
For example:

```
Wed, 25 Nov 2020 : Tue, 15 Dec 2020 => [6 (nov), 15(dec)]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear to me

Comment: We have two dates and need to find count of days between these two days, for each month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a job for `tally_by`, but that is not added to Ruby (yet?).
[tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) works too:

```
require 'date'

range = Date.parse("Wed, 25 Nov 2020") .. Date.parse("Tue, 15 Dec 2020")
p month_counts = range.map{|d| Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[d.month] }.tally
# => {"Nov"=>6, "Dec"=>15}
```

Comment: Looks like I can replace `.tally` (I am using ruby 2.6.3) with `.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash, item| hash[item] += 1; hash}`

Comment: @prosto.vint since your initial object becomes the result, you could use `each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |item, hash| hash[item] += 1 }`

Comment: `range.group_by{|d| Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[d.month] }.transform_values(&:size)` is another way.

Answer (score 2):

```
date1 = Date.new(2020, 11, 25)
date2 = Date.new(2020, 12, 15)
(date1..date2).group_by { |date| [date.year, date.month] }
              .map { |(year, month), dates| ["#{year}/#{month}", dates.length] }

 => [["2020/11", 6], ["2020/12", 15]]
```

What about the interval is so long that you have same months but of different years? I've added years because of this case.

This works in pure ruby too, you just need `require 'date'`

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
require 'date'

def count_days_by_month(str)
  Range.new(*str.split(/ +: +/).
    map { |s| Date.strptime(s, '%a, %d %b %Y') }).
    slice_when { |d1,d2| d1.month != d2.month }.
    with_object({}) do |a,h|
      day1 = a.first
      h[[day1.year, Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[day1.month]]] = a.size
    end
end
```

See [Range::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-c-new), [Date::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) and [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when).

**Examples**

```
count_days_by_month "Wed, 25 Nov 2020 : Tue, 15 Dec 2020"
  #=> {[2020, "Nov"]=>6, [2020, "Dec"]=>15}
```

```
count_days_by_month "Wed, 25 Nov 2020 : Tue, 15 Dec 2021"
  #=> {[2020, "Nov"]=>6, [2020, "Dec"]=>31, [2021, "Jan"]=>31,
  #    ...
  #    [2021, "Nov"]=>30, [2021, "Dec"]=>15}
```

**Explanation**

For the first example the steps are as follows.

```
str = "Wed, 25 Nov 2020 : Tue, 15 Dec 2020"
b = str.split(/ +: +/)
  #=> ["Wed, 25 Nov 2020", "Tue, 15 Dec 2020"] 
c = b.map { |s| Date.strptime(s, '%a, %d %b %Y') }
  #=> [#<Date: 2020-11-25 ((2459179j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2020-12-15 ((2459199j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] 
d = Range.new(*c)
  #=> #<Date: 2020-11-25 ((2459179j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>..
  #   #<Date: 2020-12-15 ((2459199j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
e = d.slice_when { |d1,d2| d1.month != d2.month }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00007fb1058abb10>:each>
```

We can see the elements generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
e.to_a
  #=> [[#<Date: 2020-11-25 ((2459179j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     #<Date: 2020-11-26 ((2459180j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     ...
  #     #<Date: 2020-11-30 ((2459184j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>],
  #    [#<Date: 2020-12-01 ((2459185j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     #<Date: 2020-12-02 ((2459186j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     ...
  #     #<Date: 2020-12-15 ((2459199j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]]
```

Continuing,

```
f = e.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00007fb1058abb10>
  #     :each>:with_object({})>
f.each do |a,h| 
  day1 = a.first
  h[[day1.year, Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[day1.month]]] = a.size 
end
  #=> {[2020, "Nov"]=>6, [2020, "Dec"]=>15}
```

The first element generated by `f` and passed to the block, and the block variables are assign values by the rules of [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition):

```
a,h = f.next
  #=> [[#<Date: 2020-11-25 ((2459179j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     #<Date: 2020-11-26 ((2459180j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     ...
  #     #<Date: 2020-11-30 ((2459184j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>],
  #     {}]
```

```
a #=> [#<Date: 2020-11-25 ((2459179j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2020-11-26 ((2459180j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    ...
  #    #<Date: 2020-11-30 ((2459184j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>],
h #=> {}
```

Key-value pairs will be added to `h` over the course of the calculations. See [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). The block calculation is now performed.

```
day1 = a.first
  #=> #<Date: 2020-11-25 ((2459179j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
g = day1.year
  #=> 2020 
i = day1.month
  #=> 11 
j = Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[day1.month]
  #=> "Nov" 
k = a.size
  #=> 6 
h[[g,j]] = k
  #=> 6
```

resulting in:

```
h #=> {[2020, "Nov"]=>6}
```

The remaining steps are similar.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by breaking the whole period into periods for each month.
Since Ruby has ranges, I'd write a helper method that takes a date range and yields month-ranges:

```
def each_month(range)
  return enum_for(__method__, range) unless block_given?

  date = range.begin.beginning_of_month
  loop do
    from = date.clamp(range)
    to   = (date.end_of_month).clamp(range)

    yield from..to

    date = date.next_month
    break unless range.cover?(date)
  end
end
```

[`clamp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Comparable.html#clamp-method) ensures that the range's bounds are taken into account when calculating each month's range. For Ruby version prior to 2.7 you have to pass the bounds separately:

```
from = date.clamp(range.begin, range.end)
to   = (date.end_of_month).clamp(range.begin, range.end)
```

Example usage:

```
from = '25 Nov 2020'.to_date
to   = '13 Jan 2021'.to_date

each_month(from..to).to_a
#=> [
#     Wed, 25 Nov 2020..Mon, 30 Nov 2020
#     Tue, 01 Dec 2020..Thu, 31 Dec 2020
#     Fri, 01 Jan 2021..Wed, 13 Jan 2021
#   ]
```

Now all we need is a way to count the days in each month-range: (e.g. via [`jd`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-jd))

```
def days(range)
  range.end.jd - range.begin.jd + 1
end
```

and some formatting:

```
each_month(from..to).map { |r| format('%d (%s)', days(r), r.begin.strftime('%b')) }
#=> ["6 (Nov)", "31 (Dec)", "13 (Jan)"]
```